# Delphi - authentication mechanism suggestions

Tags: delphi, authentication

This question has only educational purpose. At this moment I'm making a small application on which I want to include an authentication mechanism. Application should have access to Internet when is installed, but after can work offline. Until now I've thinking of the following solutions:

1) Classic: Username and password(encrypted) sent to a authentication webservice - problems when Internet connection is down.
 
2) Generate a password based on motherboard/hard-disk serial no - this is generating issues when components are changed.

Also, I want to include a 'remember password' checkbox. Which is the safest way to do this? Where should I store this info?

I believe that most of you have made an authentication mechanism, more or less complex, and I'm asking for your opinion. Also, I know that everything can be hacked but I want to make it as difficult as I can.

Comment: I am not really sure if your question is answerable in its current form.  I think that once a single-server challenge-response has been accepted, and you locally store the hash, you will find that will work well enough, but that's all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't reinvent the wheel!

Some rules:

- authentication must be per user;
- authentication must be for a session, i.e. for a network connection and some given time;
- never stores a password clearly on disk, but uses a hash;
- never transmit a password over the network, but uses a hash;
- add some "salt" (i.e. random data) during the hashing of any value;
- try to achieve some kind of [Zero-knowledge proof](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-knowledge_proof).

To make it simple, the server create a "challenge" for the client.

Typical implementation can be:

1. Client connect to a server, saying its user name;
2. Server check for the name, then create and send a challenge for the Client;
3. Client ask the user to enter its password, then use it to respond to the challenge;
4. Server receive the answer, then check the challenge is correct.

You can create a challenge using a good hashing algorithm (take a look at [our very fast SHA-256 functions](http://synopse.info/fossil/finfo?name=SynCrypto.pas)), and follow these steps:

- The User enters its initial password, then a SHA-256 is transmitted to the server (encrypted via a fixed private key e.g.);
- The Server store user names/passwords hash as key/values;
- The Server create a challenge by creating a random block (using SHA-256 of some random data, including current time and others Randomize+Random values....);
- The Client hashes this random block (received from the server) with the hash of the password just entered by the user;
- The Server receives the result from the Client, compute its own version using the stored password hash of the user, and compare the two values: challenge is successful if both value are the same.

Comment: very interesting approach! +1. but, if the user isn't connected to internet all the time? user is using the app 5 times for example, and he/she has connection only in 2 of those 5?

Comment: Well Radu, obviously the answer assumes, you are authenticating against some remote server or service.  Exactly what are you authenticating against? Do you have a design and a plan for some kind of hybrid authentication against both local and remote authorities?  Do you need a briefcase model, like NT/XP/W7 domain logins working on Windows?

Comment: For local authentification, the Client software could make a private copy of user names/passwords hash as key/values, and just compare the hash of the value entered by the User. With SHA-256, it's not possible to find two matches of the same text. User names may also be stored as SHA-256, and the whole key/value content encrypted with AES-256.

Comment: Hash are good to store "passwords", but transmitting the hash or the password makes very little difference... someone could attempt a reply attack anyway. Or you protect the channel (encrypting and or signing messages properly), or you need a more complex schema (i.e. Kerberos).

Comment: @ldsandon You're wrong: in my proposal above, the password hash is never transmitted as clear. It's transmitted after having been hashed with the "challenge" value received from the server (and some "salt" if you follow the rules). Therefore you can't go back to the password hash value just by listening to the network transmission, if you are using strong hashing like SHA-256.

Comment: No, I wasn't. Even if you use challenges and salts, you can be attacked with a men-in-the-middle approach. You have to find a way to trust the channel and its endpoints, or whatever you receive may not be from who is telling you it is..., that's why, for example, it is not enough to sign the authentication phase, but unless you encrypt properly the channel you have to sign each "packet", otherwise someone in the middle can tamper with your data and obtain what he wants (even if the data are not sensible enogh to require encription).

Comment: You're right, of course, about the MIM attack problem. The "reply attack" expression was confusing me. You should have written "replAy attack". I was talking about an authentification mechanism (which was the question point). Not about all security needs. Authentification mechanism is only one part of the whole security chain. And the greatest weakness is between the chair and the keyboard, as we all know so well. :)

Answer (score 3):

Depends on what you want to achieve. For instance, you might first retrieve some critical data from the server, then always store it locally, encrypted by login-password. This way no password is stored on the PC and you have to enter it to access the data.

Comment: +1. this is what I want to accomplish. see also what I've reply to A.Bouchez, and detail the answer please.

Answer (score 3):

Well for remembering the password, you could save its hash locally, which cannot be un-hashed to obtain the real pwd...

Answer (score 2):

You can do what browsers do using cookies and storing the password on a encrypted file or, even better, storing it to a database. Remember that you need to update the database password in case of user change it on the server.
You do not need to generate the password. You can ask user to do so, and check its complexity to ensure that it is safe. 
And always use SSL when connection to a webservice, to ensure all data is safe to transmit.

Comment: I mostly don't agree with what's being said here. Storing the password is not a good practice, encrypted or not encrypted: you'd better store the hash of the password, preferably with some salt added. I don't get the `even better, store the password to a database`. What's so special about the database? It might be more convenient, but better? What's up with `You do not need to generate the password`: who in the world would ever consider generating passwords for the user?

Comment: I did not say that storing a password is a good idea. I jsut said that he COULD do it. And if he does, its better to store it on a database because its nore likely to not loose it by accident or by users change. And i said he does not needed to generate the password because i was being polite. Of course, no one will ever do that.